# Math.Floor or Math.Truncate vs (int) in terms of Performance for Positive Numbers

Tags: c#, .net, performance, math, type-conversion

Am I correct in assuming that for this scenario:

```
double d = 3.76212; // d >= 0 && d <= Int32.MaxValue
```

One should always use this:

```
double truncated = (double)(int)d;
```

Instead of any of these:

```
double truncated = Math.Truncate(d); // 4 times slower than (double)(int) on x86, 7 times slower than (double)(int) on x64
double truncated = Math.Floor(d); // 3 times slower than (double)(int) on both x86 and x64
```

In other words, one would use Math.Floor only when working with either sufficiently large numbers (>Int32.MaxValue on x86 and > Int64.MaxValue onx64), or when dealing with numbers < 0 since Floor behaves differently with negative numbers? And as for Truncate, it's use should really be limited (short of really big negative numbers that can't fit into Int32 or Int64), because it is slower than Floor in all cases?

Comment: I would put it differently: Instead of *One should always use...*, I'd say: *If double truncation is the bottleneck in your application, use `(double)(int)d`. If it isn't, use whatever makes the intent of your code as clear as possible to your co-workers and your future self.*

Comment: `int` is always `Int32`, no matter, if the system is x86 or x64. So `double truncated = (double)(int)d;` will always fail (or worse: overflow and return negative values) for `d > Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: @Corak Yeah I know that. But if you compile for AnyCpu or x64 and run on 64-bit CPU, you can use (double)(long)d with even better performance than (double)(int)d.

Comment: It is a valid micro-optimization, the machine code for the cast can be generated inline, the Math functions require a call into a CLR helper method.  Takes a few nanoseconds longer.  Just keep in mind that the cast generates horrible data on an overflow, there's nothing pretty about getting Int32.MinValue.  The outcome is pure junk with no good way to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can assume that this will always be so, in future versions of the Framework or with future versions of the CLR.

What you could do is create a simple helper class that you call, and you hide the implementation details in that class. Then when a new CLR/Framework comes out you can re-do your measurements and update the helper class if needed:

```
double truncated = FastMath.Truncate(d);
```

and implement along the lines of

```
public static double Truncate(double d)
{
    if ((d >= Int32.MinValue) && (d <= Int32.MaxValue))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea! But that would still be a function call which is costly if you are calling it a billion times. So I guess for now, given the measurements, it is safe to assume that one should go with (double)(int). I can also find it hard to imagine that an inline conversion like that could become slower (in the future) than a function call.